# Sails vs Loopback API backend

Tags: node.js, sails.js, loopbackjs

I need a stable, robust, with easy learning curve, fast API backend framework in node js ( only apy backend service because i have already my react frontend framework).i read that in this  moment the best are Sails js and loopback. My project is a production project so i need to understand in this moment what framework between sails and loopback is more stable. what is the best for you considered the props mentioned at the begin of my message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loopback has large overhead for everything and does not handle associations good.

SailsJS has its own weakness but in my opinion, it is easier and better to make it 'your own' as it is still Express based and it is not messing enough to make you troubles with putting your own services etc.

I found Loopback as overthought. It should be simple API framework but it is massive and not easy to work with.

UPDATE: January 2021
I do not recommend using Sails anymore, as it is not actively developed anymore.
There are better alternatives like e.g. NestJS

Comment: Thanks for you is it ready sails for production enviroment ? I dont understand if sails is ready to be robust as laravel/lumen or for now i have to switch to pho solution as laravel/lumen THnaks Dario

Comment: I would say it is.

Comment: FWIW, LoopBack is Express based too, one can use any express middleware or define their own express routes as needed.

Comment: As @MiroslavBajtoš pointed out. Both are Express based. Also, they prioritise doing the heavy lifting for you (Models/Blueprints, Datasource Juggler/ORM) *and* allow customization. 
I believe a more nuanced discussion would pay attention to the differences between Loopback 3 and 4 vs Sails. But again both pretty much emphasize the same philosophy of convention over configuration.